# Ubuntu - Jenkins unable to access mounted hard disk

Tags: android, jenkins, continuous-integration

I am trying to build an apk via jenkins for my android application. I followed [this](https://pamartinezandres.com/how-to-set-up-a-continuous-integration-server-for-android-development-ubuntu-jenkins-sonarqube-43c1ed6b08d3) tutorial to do this.The issue I have is my Android sdk is installed in a separate hard disk (Not the one where jenkins is installed).

So the path I set for the sdk in the environment variable is not identified by jenkins & the build fails. But I can build an apk normally using Android studio with the same sdk path.

P.S Android studio is installed in the same hard where jenkins is installed. I referred to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10295759/jenkins-cant-access-mounted-driver) solution but still no luck. Also I cannot move the sdk to the disk where I have installed jenkins because of a disk space issue. Please can any one help me on this ?

Please refer to the console log in Jenkins

```
16:52:08 Started by user Darrel Rayen
16:52:08 Building in workspace /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/android- 
recruiter-app
16:52:08  > git rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree # timeout=10
16:52:08 Fetching changes from the remote Git repository
16:52:08  > git config remote.origin.url 
https://DarrelR@bitbucket.org/harver/android-recruiter-app.git # 
timeout=10
16:52:08 Fetching upstream changes from 
https://DarrelR@bitbucket.org/harver/android-recruiter-app.git
16:52:08  > git --version # timeout=10
16:52:08 using GIT_ASKPASS to set credentials 
16:52:08  > git fetch --tags --progress 
https://DarrelR@bitbucket.org/harver/android-recruiter-app.git 
+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
16:52:12  > git rev-parse refs/remotes/origin/master^{commit} # 
timeout=10
16:52:12  > git rev-parse refs/remotes/origin/origin/master^{commit} # 
timeout=10
16:52:12 Checking out Revision 
1609ea0ced1febf6a6cbb8bbd9488637c2c70e1a (refs/remotes/origin/master)
16:52:12  > git config core.sparsecheckout # timeout=10
16:52:12  > git checkout -f 1609ea0ced1febf6a6cbb8bbd9488637c2c70e1a
16:52:12 Commit message: "Merged in AMOB-264-end-to-end-testing-for- 
the-cand (pull request #57)"
16:52:12  > git rev-list --no-walk 
1609ea0ced1febf6a6cbb8bbd9488637c2c70e1a # timeout=10
16:52:12 [Gradle] - Launching build.
16:52:12 [android-recruiter-app] $ /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/android- 
recruiter-app/gradlew clean assembleDebug test connectedAndroidTest
16:52:12 Starting a Gradle Daemon (subsequent builds will be faster)
16:52:16 
16:52:16 FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
16:52:16 
16:52:16 * What went wrong:
16:52:16 A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
16:52:16 > The SDK directory '/media/darrel/NewDisk' does not exist.
16:52:16 
16:52:16 * Try:
16:52:16 Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with 
--info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to 
get full insights.
16:52:16 
16:52:16 * Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
16:52:16 
16:52:16 BUILD FAILED in 4s
16:52:16 Build step 'Invoke Gradle script' changed build result to 
FAILURE
16:52:16 Build step 'Invoke Gradle script' marked build as failure
16:52:17 Finished: FAILURE
```

Comment: Do you have some log? In another way, some months ago , I was able to compile an apk without Android Studio. Android Studio has a lot of unused dependencies. Are you interested?

Comment: Hi @JRichardsz I have added the error log. Can you help on  this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution for my problem from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20584112/6413802). I had to update the access permission for the user to access the mounted drive using the below steps

1.Unmount the mounted device (**/dev/sdb** is the hard disk detected name)

```
umount /dev/sdb
chmod -R 0777 /mnt/
```

2.Finally mount the hard

```
mount /dev/sdb /mnt
```

3.Then I gave the sdk path as /mnt/Android/Sdk